# Is a Reverse Proxy needed for Firebase Hosting?

Tags: reverse-proxy, firebase-hosting

I reading an [article](https://medium.com/intrinsic/why-should-i-use-a-reverse-proxy-if-node-js-is-production-ready-5a079408b2ca) about reverse-proxies. Among the benefits listed are

1. Enable HTTPS support
2. Gzip responses

I am wondering if I should concern myself with these if I am leveraging Firebase Hosting? I wasn't able to find any information on these topic within their documentation. **In short, do I need a reverse-proxy with Firebase hosting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting already uses HTTPS, and Gzips most responses.

Even if it didn't, there is no requirement to have HTTPS and/or Gzip. If you don't know whether you need them, you probably shouldn't spend time on adding them.